# How to get Odoo Inventory adjustment value through SQL

Tags: sql, odoo, odoo-12

I am working on a custom stock valuation module and in one model I am trying to get adjustment value for a lot - product - warehouse wise of the previous day.

### QUERY 1

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT stock_inventory.date AS stock_adjustment_date,
stock_move_line.lot_id,
stock_move_line.product_id,
SUM(stock_move_line.qty_done) total_stock_adjustment

FROM stock_move_line

LEFT JOIN stock_move ON stock_move_line.move_id = stock_move.id
LEFT JOIN stock_inventory ON stock_move.inventory_id = stock_inventory.id

WHERE stock_move.inventory_id IS NOT NULL
AND stock_move_line.location_id = 5
AND stock_move_line.location_dest_id = 13
AND stock_move_line.lot_id IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY stock_move_line.lot_id, stock_move_line.product_id, stock_inventory.date

ORDER BY total_stock_adjustment DESC
)
 testTable;
```

### QUERY 2

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT stock_inventory.date AS stock_adjustment_date,
stock_move_line.lot_id,
stock_move_line.product_id,
SUM(stock_move_line.qty_done) total_stock_adjustment

FROM stock_move_line

LEFT JOIN stock_move ON stock_move_line.move_id = stock_move.id
LEFT JOIN stock_inventory ON stock_move.inventory_id = stock_inventory.id

WHERE stock_move.inventory_id IS NOT NULL
AND stock_move_line.location_id = 13
AND stock_move_line.location_dest_id = 5
AND stock_move_line.lot_id IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY stock_move_line.lot_id, stock_move_line.product_id, stock_inventory.date

ORDER BY total_stock_adjustment DESC
)
 testTable;
```

Why these both queries returning same count 14,849 ?

13 is the warehouse ID and 5 is the virtual location used for adjustment. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: which is the difference between the tow query ? ..  at a first look seems the same-

Comment: location_id and location_dest_id actually. location_id 13 is my primary location and 5 is the virtual location for adjustment.

Comment: How do you expect us to answer? Apparently both queries return the same number of rows. Maybe they are different rows, but maybe not. Why do you expect them to return a different number?